# Check for unicode range with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, unicode, casperjs

I am trying to check for Chinese characters using the unicode range`[\u4e00-\u9fa5]` but my casperjs script is failing.

This is what I am attempting to do,

```
casper.test.begin('unicode test', 1, function(test) {
    casper.start('http://us.weibo.com/gb', function(){
        test.assertMatch(/[\u4e00-\u9fa5]/, 'checking for ch characters');
    }).run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

This is a portion of the test results,

Details for the 1 failed test:

```
In check-for-ch-char.js:628
  unicode test
    uncaughtError: Invalid regexp.
```

If I copy/paste any characters from the start url I can see that the unicode range works [here](http://regexr.com/3bcvc) using regexr.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. I am not really sure why, as I am fairly new to casperjs so if someone can elaborate on this that would be useful.

I edited my test like so `test.assertMatch(this.page.content, /[\u4e00-\u9fa5]/, 'checking for ch characters');` and what this did is it looked for content to match the unicode range against. Before, I had `test.assertMatch(/[\u4e00-\u9fa5]/, 'checking for ch characters');` and the range was not looking at anything, but I thought it would be looking at the start url for this content automatically.

So, including `this.page.content` did the trick it seems.